# Reverse array with recursion C++

Tags: c++, arrays, recursion

My main idea is to shrink they array from both sides . For example if the input is 1234 , wanna print 1234 and then 4321 (the reversed) .

```
#include <iostream>
#include <cmath>
#include <math.h>

using namespace std;

int reversedArray(int* x)
{
    cout<< "*x out of  while =" << *x <<endl ;
    while( *x != 0 )
    {
        cout << "*x=" << *x << endl;
        cout<< "====================== im in reversed   =================" << endl ;
        return reversedArray( x+1  );
    }
    cout<< "after return           "  << *x << endl;
}

int main ()
{
    int Array[] = {10,2,3,4,8 ,0} ;
    int* p_Array = Array;
    reversedArray( Array );
}
```

After the "while" , why the functions that are in the stack, do not return to the next line ( " the -->  cout<< "after return           "  <<*x <

Comment: you're taking in a pointer as an argument in to the function and in the recursion part you are giving it an integer..`return reversedArray( x+1  );`

Comment: Why do you declare it to return `int`? It never returns anything in the base case of the recursion.

Comment: The right tool to solve such problems is your debugger. You should step through your code line-by-line *before* asking on Stack Overflow. For more help, please read [How to debug small programs (by Eric Lippert)](https://ericlippert.com/2014/03/05/how-to-debug-small-programs/). At a minimum, you should \[edit] your question to include a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) example that reproduces your problem, along with the observations you made in the debugger.

Comment: @Hawk  My idea is to make the pointer, to point to the next element

Comment: @Hawk That's exactly what adding to a pointer does. That's basic C pointer arithmetic.

Answer (score 1):

```
void printReversed(int * x)
{
    if (*x == 0) return;

    std::cout << *x;
    printReversed(x+1);
    std::cout << *x;
}
```

Comment: How does this answer the question he asked in the last line?

Answer (score 1):

The line:

```
return reversedArray( x+1  );
```

exits the function. So you never repeat the `while` or execute any of the code after the `while` if you go into the `while`. This makes the `while` effectively an `if` statement.

Comment: Why it exits the function ? 
Why my function isn't hold in  stack ?

Comment: Because that's what a `return` statement does, it exits the current function. In the case of a recursive function, it exits the current invocation, returning to the one that called it. Then that one returns as well, and so on.

Comment: thank you very much! i was confused with a similar example. But you helped me understand it ! thank you very much!

Answer (score 1):

The code posted by Crazy Eddie does the job and Barmar explains the ineffectiveness of the while loop. I decided to post a non-recursive way to address the problem mentioned.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>
using namespace std;


vector<int> reverseArray(vector<int>& arr) {
    vector<int> ans;
    int n = arr.size();

    // insert all elements in the reverse order
    for (size_t i = 0; i < n; i++) {
        ans.push_back(arr[n-i-1]);
    }

    return ans;
}

int main ()
{
    int array[] = {10, 2, 3, 4, 8, 0};
    // convert into vector
    vector<int> arr(array, array+6);
    vector<int> rev = reverseArray(arr);
    // merging the 2 arrays
    arr.insert(arr.end(), rev.begin(), rev.end());
    // printArray(arr) -- implement to fit your needs;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

When you pass an `int[]` to a function it decays to an `int*` which is simply an address in memory. C++ a better plan would be to use [`copy_backward`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/copy_backward) with an [`ostream_iterator`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/iterator/ostream_iterator):

```
copy_backward(Array, Array + sizeof(Array) / sizeof(*Array), ostream_iterator<int>(cout, " "))
```

Note that this method uses the actual size of the array, and does not depend upon a terminal element. Thus, no numbers are offlimits, and it's impossible to segfault by failing to provide the terminating element.

If you have access to C++11 you can simplify that a bit further to:

```
copy(crbegin(Array), crend(Array), ostream_iterator<int>(cout, " "))
```

[<kbd>Live Example</kbd>](http://ideone.com/3Zecbr)